# Project permission on Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, branching-and-merging, user-permissions

I am trying to put **project level permission** on my project for some git users on Bitbucket repository as.. [image: Project Permissions]

also for the repository in the project i have used **branch permissions** as

[image: Branch Permissions]

According to these permission user "Rahul" should not be able to push changes into "develop" branch, but is not so... user "Rahul" able to make changes on all the branches. If any could please suggest where am i going wrong..

[image]

Also no Global permissions have been given to user "rahul"
[image]

Comment: No idea. Try with another user and see if perhaps Rahul has something different e.g. some administrator role. Double check you've applied the permissions to the correct repository.

Comment: Nope.. user "rahul" is not administrator.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Rahul has some global permission. Check it at:

```
Bitbucket > Administration > Global permissions
```

Or execute:

```
curl -s --user USER:PASS --request GET https://BITBUCKET-SERVER/rest/api/1.0/admin/permissions/users | jq --raw-output '.values[] | .user.name + " " + .permission'
```

You need to have Admin permission.

Comment: checked the same..  no global permissions have been provided to user "rahul". Added screen shot of permissions in question

Comment: So you checket the global permissions, project permissions and the branch permissions... have you checked the repository permissions? If everything is ok with this last item: are you sure that Rahul is push using "rahul" permissions? I mean, looking at your console image there's no evidence that the "git push  develop" was executed with user "rahul" credentials.

Comment: can u please explain how to check for the same ??

Comment: You can check the repository permissions at the repository page > Settings > Repository permissions. You can check the user which is executing the push with commands like: whoami, git remote -v, etc

Answer (score 0):

Rahul should has write access to push the changes into repository. So provide repository level write access to Rahul.

Comment: Hi Sriram, Actually i dont want rahul to push changes to **develop** repository.